# AWS Cognito: Why does authenticateUser() take 14 seconds to complete?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When I login to my application using all of the AWS Cognito bits associated with the aws-sdk-2.4.12 release, I find that the authenticateUser() function takes roughly 14 seconds to complete.  (This slow response behavior is not new - prior releases were also slow.)

Using Fiddler2, it appears that 6 seconds are used up before the tunnel is sent to 'cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443, and then 8 seconds later the call completes successfully.

The question is:   Why is this so slow and can anything be done to speed it up?
Here's my code:

```
// Login
self.loginUser = function (username, password) {
    var authData = {
        Username: username,
        Password: password
    };

    var authDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authData);

    var userData = {
        Username: username,
        Pool: self.userPool
    };

    cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('loginUser: ' + username);
        },
        onFailure: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('FAIL loginUser: ' + username);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Same here, when all source code is in AWS Lambda function

Answer (score 0):

My bad. This is a non-problem.  It's an artifact of debugging my code in Visual Studio 2015.

Here are timing results to login for each browser, running on desktop, Win7x64.

Time to login:

- Firefox: 1.5 seconds
- Chrome: 2 seconds
- IE 11: 3 seconds
- **IE 11 debugging with VS2015: 14 seconds**

This is the first time I've noticed that VS2015 significantly affecting javascript performance.  Anybody have a theory why?